# PostgreSQL RLS explicit Policies

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, security-policy

Are the below implementation of policies equivalent from a security point of view ?

Implicit:

```
CREATE POLICY test_access_policy ON test 
  TO PUBLIC 
  USING (id = (current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT))) 
  WITH CHECK (TRUE);
```

Explicit:

```
CREATE POLICY test_insert_policy ON test 
  FOR INSERT TO PUBLIC
  WITH CHECK (TRUE);   

CREATE POLICY test_select_policy ON test
  FOR SELECT TO PUBLIC 
  USING (id = (current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT)));  

CREATE POLICY test_update_policy ON test 
  FOR UPDATE TO PUBLIC
  USING (id = (current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT)));   

CREATE POLICY test_delete_policy ON test 
  FOR DELETE TO PUBLIC 
USING (id = (current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT)));
```

My concern is the UPDATE policy, as stated in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createpolicy.html):

> Any rows whose updated values do not pass the WITH CHECK expression
> will cause an error, and the entire command will be aborted. If only a
> USING clause is specified, then that clause will be used for both
> USING and WITH CHECK cases.

From my understanding the equivalent UPDATE policy for the implicit version (oneliner) is the following:

```
CREATE POLICY test_update_policy ON test 
  FOR UPDATE TO PUBLIC 
  USING (id = (current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT))) WITH CHECK (TRUE);
```

whereas the explicit version is:

```
CREATE POLICY test_update_policy ON test 
  FOR UPDATE TO PUBLIC 
  USING (id = (current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT))) WITH CHECK (id =
(current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT)));
```

After testing both cases I didn't find any security bridge am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct, and you'd have to add `WITH CHECK (TRUE)` to the `FOR UPDATE` policy to have an equivalent definition.

The difference is that `WITH CHECK (TRUE)` allows you to change the value to anything, and without it you will receive an error if the new row version does not match the condition.

Comment: thanks for the response. my question though focus on what are the implications of the `USING (id = (current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT))) 
  WITH CHECK (TRUE)` vs `USING (id = (current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT))) WITH CHECK (id =
(current_setting('rls.id'::TEXT)))` on the `FOR UPDATE` policy. 
Docs -> while the WITH CHECK expression defines which modified rows are allowed to be >stored back into the relation.
for the former case would this mean that it would potentially allow you to update the `id` of the record ?

Comment: I have added an explanation.